# Fetching docker images versions from artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to get a list of  versions for a  specific docker image  from Artifactory.

Same as you have a maven **meta-data.xml** file that you can manipulate in to lists you all the versions of a maven artifact.
From referring the Artifactory documentation I didn't see any api for this kind of request.

Has anyone done that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing the topics of what's considered a version for maven/gradle with a version inside of Docker.  Docker images do not have a version concept, rather the concept is tags.  A tag may be a version, but could also be a Git commit hash, or other meaningful identifier.

Since you already know the docker image, you should be able to use the Docker API specification which has been implemented for Artifactory.

[Docker API -- Listing Image Tags](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags)

[Artifactory API -- Listing Tags](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ListDockerTags)

You should be able to request from artifactory on the API endpoint for listing tags.

```
/v2/library/nginx/tags/list
```

Example:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET https://docker.artifactory.site.com/artifactory/v2/library/nginx/tags/list
```

Should result in the listing in all of the tags for Nginx.

```
{
    "name": "library/nginx",
    "tags": [
        "1",
        "1-alpine",
        "1-alpine-perl",
        "1-perl",
        "1.10",
        "1.10-alpine",
...
...
```